# Why does an IIFE need a semicolon?

Tags: javascript

Why does an IIFE need a semicolon? Why doesn't it just read the newlines as linebreaks? The following code:

```
(function(){
  console.log(`Hello there`)
})()

(function(){
  console.log(`IIFE ran..`)
})()
```

returns:

```
temp.js:2 Hello there
temp.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
    at temp.js:5
```

However, the following does work:

```
(function(){
  console.log(`Hello there`)
})();

(function(){
  console.log(`IIFE ran..`)
})()
```

Edit: Thanks for the comments. The help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Because a `()` followed by a `(` is valid syntax, so no semicolon is inserted

Comment: With your syntax first function is called with second function and not as separate functions